# Use ILMerge to Bypass GAC

Tags: c#, .net, ilmerge

If you reference a strongly named assembly, which is installed in the GAC, a Winforms application will look in the GAC for it's reference first.

Is it possible to bypass the GAC by merging the strongly named assembly into winforms exe using ILMerge? I attempted this without success - seeking confirmation that my POC was not a false negative.

Comment: Not much point in guessing at this, show us the Fuslogvw.exe trace.

Comment: You could also consider bypassing the GAC loading using the AssemblyLoadContext class, the [Load Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext?view=net-5.0) provides the first chance to resolve the assembly.

Comment: @Adam I think that is specific to .net core or newer, and doesn't apply to framework